# how to remove dual boot ubuntu 13.10 and install Ubuntu server 14

Tags: server, 13.10, 14.10

I currently have Ubuntu desktop 14.10 and 13.10 installed as dual boot. How can I remove 13.10 and install the Ubuntu server in its place?

Answer (score 1):

you can delete the 13.10 partition using `gparted` from within the 14.10 OS, and then proceed to a normal install of the Ubuntu server, if it happens that grub get broken, it is fine as the Ubuntu server would fix it